# Cant connect to my Ubuntu Api

Tags: windows, vmware, firewall, nginx

I'm using ubuntu on VM , I can ping it also its ok on sharing folders and etc.
I've run a NginX and deploy an Simple Api on it and its ok on local machine.
but I cant call the Api from the outside , ive tried another ubuntu and another windows,
I've tried disabling both my windows and ubuntu firewalls,
I've tried add allowed ports both on ubuntu and windows.
I donno what to do

Answer (score 0):

so I've done some research and the answer was a problem in Nginx configures not the network or firewall itself,
the port that used in app is not the same as the port it used to expose and called from another nodes in network ,
so that was it